# No specific word allowed before a specific pattern at the end of the string

Tags: regex

in one of some configs files i have the next RegEx: `/\.story\.jsx?$/`
It's select all files with 'story.jsx' in name, but i also want ignore file if his name has 'template' word. How can i do this with single RegEx: if (.story.jsx && !template) ?

Comment: Your current positive match regex already ignores the negative case, right?

Comment: `/^(?!.*template).*\.story\.jsx?$/` - all you need is to add the negative lookahead check at the start of the string and then consume all chars there are before your string suffix.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen no, it's does not ignore anything, its just select all files with .story.js in name, but i want also ignore files .template.story.js with the same RegEx

Comment: `(?!.*template)` supplied above by Wiktor ignores anything with the word template in it. Its a negative look ahead.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks, this is work!

Comment: After the [comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53205186/regex-if-file-name-not-contain-specific-word#comment93298649_53205186), I changed the dupe reason, and your regex can be precised as `/^(?!.*\.template\.story\.jsx?$).*\.story\.jsx?$/`